# How to save memory when using multiple, near-identical, BTreeMaps?

Tags: rust, structural-sharing

I have multiple BTreeMaps, where each is nearly-identical to its parent, with the exception of a few added and removed keys/values.

Currently, I'm using `.clone()` on the parent, to create a child which is then modified to be marginally different.  I believe this wastes large amounts of memory.

The following conditions apply:

- Each BTreeMap is unchanged after it is created.
- There is only ever one valid value for each key, across all trees.
- Each child contains 95%+ of the keys of its parent and may contain 5% new keys.
- Parent BTreeMaps can be discarded.
- Keys are tens of bytes and values are thousands.
- BTreeMap was chosen because of the need to deterministically serialize to JSON objects.

Ideally, the solution will only store one copy of each key and value.

I can implement a custom solution myself, but I'm asking if there's already a solution to structural sharing in Rust.

Comment: How is this different by just building a tree piecewise by adding and occasionally removing elements? Why add `clone` to this process? Just wondering.

Comment: The `im` crate implements functionally updated structurally shared collections. I don't know if it's serde-compatible out of the box tho.

Comment: Can you use `BTreeMap<Rc<K>, Rc<V>>` instead of `BreeMap<K, V>`? That way the tree nodes are still duplicated, but the keys and values are only stored once.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. The parent `BTreeMap`s provide a history, which can be queried.

Comment: You said "Parent BTreeMaps can be discarded"...

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  Sorry, I wasn't clear.  They can be discarded, but not immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`im` crate](https://lib.rs/crates/im) sounds like what you want. Its `OrdMap` type implements structural sharing while copying the `BTreeMap` API. With the `serde` feature, the types will implement `serde::Serialize` and `serde::Deserialize`.

If you want to stick with the std library's `BTreeMap` type, consider using `Rc`/`Arc` for the keys/values. This will let your trees share the same storage for the keys/values, which can help if they are large, but the tree itself will not share storage.